# how to repaint JPanel after events occured

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, repaint

I'm trying to repaint JPanel after events occured. I don't really know how  `.repaint()` and `.revalidate()` works. Everybody tells me it'll work but not for mine.

My code consists of ParentFrame, ChildFrame and Test Class. Test Class is just for `main` function.

My project is a bit more complicated than following code but I just picked only thing that I need to figure out.

So basically, ParentFrame shows Strings from ArrayList that I defined. Once I click `EDIT` button, ChildFrame shows up. Then I fill in JTextField and click `OK` button.
Then ChildFrame has to be gone and ParentFrame should be repainted with newly edited ArrayList.

My project uses `addMouseListener` to pick which one should be edited but I just deleted it. Because only thing I need to figure out is just how to repaint JPanel. I just set the target as `list.get(0)` which is the first one.

I tried to repaint with trying `panel.revalidate();` + `panel.repaint();` but doesn't work at all.

Here's my code. NEED YOUR HELP!!!

**ParentFrame**

```
public class ParentFrame extends JFrame {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(){{add("test1"); add("test2");}};
    JPanel big;
    JLabel content;
    
    public ParentFrame() {
        super("parent");
        super.setSize(200,200);
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        big = new JPanel();
        
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            content = new JLabel();
            content.setText(list.get(i));

            big.add(content);
        }
        super.add(big, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton edit = new JButton("EDIT");
        edit.addActionListener(new EditListener());
        super.add(edit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    public ArrayList<String> getParentList() {
        return list;
    }
    
    public void setParentList(int i, String b) {
        this.list.set(i,b);
    }

    public class EditListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ChildFrame child = new ChildFrame(ParentFrame.this);
            list = child.newList;
            
            big.revalidate();
            big.repaint();
        }
    } 
}
```

**ChildFrame**

```
public class ChildFrame extends JFrame {
    ArrayList<String> newList;
    
    public ChildFrame(ParentFrame pF) {
        super("child");
        super.setSize(100,100);
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                
        newList = pF.getParentList();
        
        JTextField edit = new JTextField(pF.getParentList().get(0));
        add(edit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
        ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                newList.set(0, edit.getText());

                dispose();
            }
        });
        add(ok, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            ParentFrame pF = new ParentFrame();
    }
}
```

As you can see from ParentFrame code, I placed `.revalidate()` and `.repaint()` in `EditListener`'s function `actionPerformed`. But it doesn't work...

Comment: You should be using a JList or a JTable in your parent JFrame.  Your child JFrame should be a JDialog.

Comment: See: [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` example shows how to maintain data in a JList. The point is you update the `ListModel` and the `JList` will automatically repaint itself. Yes, in the example the Hire/Filre button are all on the same panel. but that is irrelevant. If you want the buttons on a different panel, then you just pass the `ListModel` as a parameter to that dialog and when you update the model the list will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware calling repaint() does not paint the component on the screen. It rather marks the component as dirty (which means it is pending for repaint).
The actual repaint is happening on the Event Dispatching Thread.

Now when some event happens your event handler is triggered, and very likely you update your model and want to trigger the repaint. But be aware the event handler is triggered using the event dispatcher thread, and as long as you block that thread no repaint can happen.

So you can actually do one of two things:

- Use quick actions to update the model, then trigger the repaint using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)).
- For longer running actions create a separate Thread to perform the action, which would then notify the UI to repaint.

Examples how to do this are plenty on the web, one of them is https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem can solved by using:

```
setVisible(false);
setVisible(true);
```

on the jPanel